# API to access Google Profile on Android

Tags: android, api, identity

Google accounts come with a pretty nice profile already, and since all Android phones connect to that profile for most of the google services.  I'd like to add an option to my application to simply register with my application using your google profile on the phone.  Not only would I have access to information like email address, name, aliases, but also profile images people use on google services.

Which Google API provides me access to that?  Is there something in the Android API's that already provides this that I'm missing?  I'm not just looking for authentication, as with OAUTH, but access to the profile information as well.

Are there any existing libraries I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a way to get access to the google profile(s) the user has:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager

That's awesome.